# Remove new type of ad on Windows 10 search bar after Windows update

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, taskbar, spam-prevention, adware

After a recent windows update this ad is now showing up on the search bar

[image]

It a small button on the right of the search bar, and if you hover (or click) over it it shows a panel as shown

How do I get rid of this button on the search bar? Right clicking it does not show any relevant options (it just opens up the taskbar right click menu).

Using Windows 10 professional version 21H2 (OS Build 19044.1706)

Comment: @john I don't think this is news and interest OR weather information

Comment: @ closevoter care to explain?

Comment: @john it's already off. I turned it off months ago when the "news and interest" thing started showing up after a windows update at that time. This one is a completely new thing

Comment: @john I can't find the options to turn it into a magnifying glass. I don't mind it being a bar, that's the way I have had it for a long time. I just want to uninstall what ever new ad the latest update added.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right click task bar -> search -> uncheck "Show Search Highlights" and it disappears

[image]