# windows key needs to be pressed several times before reacting

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-11

Seems like something have broken in Windows and it happens on both my home PC with Windows 10 and my work laptop with Windows 11! If I press win key to bring up start menu and type something I almost always need to press it several times before anything happens!

The same issue is with <kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> which I frequently use to make screenshot - I have to press it multiple times before it decides to appear! This is really annoying. When it kind of "wakes up" then it seems to be working normally for some time and start menu comes up immediately, but after some time or putting the PC to sleep and waking it up, it gets lazy again.

Do you experience the same and have some idea what the heck is this? Both those PCs are pretty high-end and nothing weird is running and consuming my CPU or RAM, so it's not a performance issue.

**Edit**: Other apps key shortcuts like GeForce experience <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> seems to be working every time.

Comment: Is this true of your work laptop at your work location?  Have you done full  virus scans?

Comment: how is location relevant? I am working mostly from home. Why would it behave differently when I go into the office? But I can try that if you wish... I don't really do manual virus scans. I rely on windows defender and also look at task manager frequently, because AV software became a security risk and a performance eaters in recent years. Just read about Symantec and their fake certificates for example.

Comment: I think there are some components of the WinKey results that are dependent on internet, so that is why I asked about location.

Comment: are you serious? What components? My home internet is one of the best available with latency around 10ms...

Comment: WinKey and Start Button both use Internet components. There was a big Start button Outage several years ago. Microsoft issue.  There is not much other reason why 2 computers with 2 OSs would have the SAME fault other than Internet or Viruses.

Comment: As @John states, Win key, by *itself*, is used to start Search. Microsoft uses Search to show advertising, *downloaded from the web*: https://superuser.com/questions/1722140/remove-new-type-of-ad-on-windows-10-search-bar-after-windows-update Turn off advertising and other web "enhancements" in Search.

Comment: If you are sure there are no viruses, you may wish to reset your router and set it up again to ensure all is smooth.

Comment: So I have unchecked Show Search Highlights, but I doubt this is related...